# SPService GetListItems with CAML : can't get the example to work with status giving error

Tags: javascript, spservices

I am new to SPServices and trying start with example GetListItems.
Below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    GetTasks();
});

function GetTasks()
{

    var method = "GetListItems";
    var list = "Tasks";
    var fieldsToRead ="<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields>";
    var query ="<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Counter'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
            $().SPServices({
            operation: method,
            async: false,  
            listName: list,
            CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,

              completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
                    debugger;
                    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() { 

                       alert("hello");
                        var name = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
                    });                
                }
    });
}
```

The debugger in the completefunc is hit but when I check the status of `function(xData, status)` the status returns "error".And after this `alert("hello")` does not hit.

What is that I am doing wrong in this ?

Comment: It is before that I am getting the status as error

Comment: @Amal Yes it is.

Comment: @AmalHashim No it just gives "error".

Comment: Where is this code being executed from? A webpart?

Comment: @PaulT. It is being executed from the site home page and the task list is present in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $().SPServices({
        webUrl: "http://weburl/"
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Tasks",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                alert($(this).attr("ows_Title"));                   
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Change `webUrl` to the current web where `Tasks` list resides.

Comment: It did not work. From which version of IE does spservices support. Mine is IE 8 . Is this the problem.

Comment: Fiddler event log says AutoProxyDetection failed

Comment: Is your SharePoint site on premise, do you have any proxy settings in IE?

Comment: It is on premise and there are no proxy settings in IE